# HTML and PHP pagination not working correctly

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a bit of code that pulls all the results from a database and displays the ones that are relevant to the users search. I have some more code that counts the amount of items and generates a certain amount of pages based on how many items are relevant to the users search. The problem is as follows. If I do a search all, my code displays everything in the database on 11 pages. If I search for car, it will still display 11 pages but only 2 results that have the word car in the title. The problem is that these results display on the eighth page and all other pages are blank. During the search all the two results with car in the title displayed on the eighth page as well. The search all is based on the order the items are in, in the database. Here is my current code:

```
                $pagesQuery  = mysql_query("SELECT count(id) FROM(`posts`)");
                $pageNum = ceil(mysql_result($pagesQuery, 0)/5);
                $start = (($page-1)*5);


                $currentname = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT $start, 5");  
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($currentname)) {
                        //recieve relevant data.
                        $title = $row[0];
                        $desc = $row[13];
                        $ID = $row[6];
                        $views = $row[3];
                        $user = $row[7];
                        //fetch the last id from accounts table.
                        $fetchlast1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM allaccounts WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM allaccounts)");
                        $lastrow1 = mysql_fetch_row($fetchlast1);
                        $lastid1 = $lastrow1[6];
                        //acquire the username of postee.
                        for ($i1=1; $i1 <= $lastid1; $i1++) { 
                            $currentname1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM allaccounts WHERE id=$user");
                            while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($currentname1)) {
                                $username1 = $row1[0];
                            }
                        }

                        //Format Title, description and view count.
                        $title2 = rtrim($title);
                        $donetitle = str_replace(" ", "-", $title2);
                        $url = "articles/".$ID."/".$donetitle."";

                        $donetitle = strlen($title) > 40 ? substr($title,0,40)."..." : $title;
                        $donedesc = '';

                        if(strlen($desc) > 150) {
                            $donedesc = explode( "\n", wordwrap( $desc, 150));
                            $donedesc1 = $donedesc[0] . '...';                          
                        }else{
                            $donedesc1 = $desc;                         
                        }
                        $finviews = number_format($views, 0, '.', ',');

                        //Give relevant results
                        if(stripos($title, $terms) !== false || stripos($desc, $terms) !== false || stripos($username1, $terms) !== false){
                                if($row[10] == null){
                                    $SRC = "img/tempsmall.jpg";
                                }else{
                                    $SRC ="generateThumbnailSmall.php?id=$ID"; 
                                }
                                echo "<div id = \"feature\">

                                       <img src=\"$SRC\" alt = \"article thumbnail\" />
                                      </div>
                                        <div id = \"feature2\">
                                             <a href= \"$url\" id = \"titletext\" alt = \"article title\">$donetitle</a>
                                             <p id=\"resultuser\" >$username1</p>
                                             <p id=\"resultp\">$donedesc1</p>
                                             <a href = \"sendflag.php?title=$title&url=$url&id=$ID&userid=$user\" id = \"flag\" alt = \"flag\"><img src=\"img/icons/flag.png\"/></a><b id=\"resultview\">$finviews views</b> 

                                        </div>
                                      <div id = \"border\"></div>";
                        }






                }



                    $totalPages = $pageNum;
                    $currentPage = $page;
                    $numPagesToShow = 10;

                    if($currentPage > $totalPages) {
                        $currentPage = $totalPages;
                    }


                    if($numPagesToShow >= $totalPages) {
                        $numMaxPageLeft = 1;
                        $numMaxPageRight = $totalPages;
                    } else {
                        $pagesToShow = ceil($numPagesToShow/2);
                        $numMaxPageLeft = $currentPage - $pagesToShow;
                        $numMaxPageRight = $currentPage + $pagesToShow;

                        if($numMaxPageLeft <= 0) {
                            $numMaxPageRight = $numMaxPageRight - $numMaxPageLeft +1;
                            $numMaxPageLeft = 1;
                        } elseif($numMaxPageRight >= $totalPages) {
                            $numMaxPageLeft -= ($numMaxPageRight - $totalPages);
                            $numMaxPageRight = $totalPages;
                        }
                    }

                    for ($i=$numMaxPageLeft; $i<=$numMaxPageRight; $i++) {
                        echo "<a id =\"pagenationlink\" href=\"searchresults.php?search=".$terms."&page=".$i."\">".$i."</a>";
                    }
```

How can I only display one page with the two results on it instead of 11 pages with the two relevant results on the eighth page? Thanks

Comment: Don't fetch all the records. Only fetch the records that are relevant and matches the search.

Comment: Don't use the deprecated `mysql_*`-functions. They are deprecated since PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7. They are also insecure. Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: explain how to do this to me please

Comment: The first comment: Use a "where" in your query to find the relevant rows (what to search for depends on your DB and search etc). The second comment, rewrite your application to use PDO or MySQLi. Read the PHP-documentation about those.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your code as below.
But try to use mysqli_*() as mysql*() are depricted

```
$cond = "";
if(!empty($_POST["search"]))
{    
   $cond = " write your search condition " ;
}
$start = (($page-1)*5);
$query  = mysql_query("SELECT  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM posts where $cond LIMIT $start, 5");
$TotalDataQuery = mysql_query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() tot;");
$rsVal = mysql_fetch_array($pagesQuery);
$pagesQuery = $rsVal['tot'];
$pageNum = ceil($pagesQuery/5);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
 //continue your code
}
```